# Parse only specific field from application.yml

Tags: java, spring

I need help with my Spring application configuration file.

I have configuration looks like this:

```
integration
mapping:
    - producer:
        name: somename
        topic: sometopic
        replyTopic: sometopic
        replyPartition: 1
    consumer:
        name: somename
        field_1: ...
        field_2: ...
    - producer:
        name: somename
        topic: sometopic
        replyTopic: sometopic
        replyPartition: 1
    consumer:
        name: somename
        field_1: ...
        field_2: ...
```

And i need to extract all of the fields 'replyTopic' from this configuration. I understand that i can map all of this configs to class with ConfigurationProperties annotation, but i wanna only field replyTopic in order to put this in @KafkaListener annotation, which requires to get topic names in the startup of the application.

So basically i want something like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = '*some expression to extract all of replyTopic from congiration*')
```

Thanks!

Comment: if my answer helps request you to please accept it so that it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation itself. Here is the solution.

```yaml
integration:
  mapping:
    - producer:
        name: somename1
        topic: sometopic1
        replyTopic: sometopic1
        replyPartition: 1
      consumer:
        name: somename1
        field_1: ...
        field_2: ...
    - producer:
        name: somename2
        topic: sometopic2
        replyTopic: sometopic2
        replyPartition: 1
      consumer:
        name: somename2
        field_1: ...
        field_2: ...
```

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "integration")
public class AppConfig {
    private List<Mapping> mapping;

    public List<Mapping> getMapping() {
        return mapping;
    }

    public void setMapping(List<Mapping> mapping) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Mapping {
    private Producer producer;

    private Consumer consumer;

    public Producer getProducer() {
        return producer;
    }

    public void setProducer(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }


    public Consumer getConsumer() {
        return consumer;
    }

    public void setConsumer(Consumer consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mapping{" +
                "producer=" + producer +
                ", consumer=" + consumer +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
public class Producer {
    private String replyTopic;

    public String getReplyTopic() {
        return replyTopic;
    }

    public void setReplyTopic(String replyTopic) {
        this.replyTopic = replyTopic;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Producer{" +
                "replyTopic='" + replyTopic + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
public class Consumer {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Consumer{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        final List<Mapping> mapping = appConfig.getMapping();
        final List<String> replyTopics = mapping.stream()
                .map(Mapping::getProducer)
                .map(Producer::getReplyTopic)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(replyTopics);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[sometopic1, sometopic2]

*I hope this solves your query.*